# "Best fit" text option to shrink only

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there an easy way to dynamically resize a text to fit its contents, *not exceeding certain maximum size*? I mean, something like one-way "best fit" option, one that shrinks only.

I tried to manipulate the size of the best-fit text by script, but that doesn't do anything:

```
private void ModifyText(Text text, string str, int maxSize)
{
    text.text = str;
    if (text.fontSize > maxSize) text.fontSize = maxSize;
}
```

Comment: *"not exceeding certain maximum size?"* You mean the font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best fit lets you define minimum and maximum font sizes, right in the inspector[image: inspector]

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice :)